# Unit Testing UseState when its Setter function is passed to a Child Component

Tags: javascript, jestjs, use-state

Below I have a an example of UseState hook where its setter function (**setInputs**) is passed down to a child component (**LoginForm**).

I am having trouble with Unit Testing where I cannot simulate a change to `setInputs` and thereby cannot assert that the dispatch is called.

How can I simulate a change to the `setInputs` prop in order to update the `inputs` state in my Test?

**Component:**

```
const Login = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ email: '' });

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!inputs.email) {
      return;
    }
    // Cannot Assert this
    dispatch(requestAuthentication(inputs.email));
  };

  return (
    <LoginForm
      setInputs={setInputs}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
    />
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Login Form **

Is a basic form than onChange of an input calls the following function

```
const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();

    props.setInputs(input => ({
      ...input,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };
```

**Unit Test:**

```
it('should return if no email is entered', () => {
    useDispatch.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
    useSelector.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());

    requestAuthentication.mockImplementation((data, callback) => {
      callback();
    });

    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Login>
        <LoginForm {...props} />
      </Login>
    );

    wrapper
      .find('LoginForm')
      .props()
      .handleSubmit({
        preventDefault: () => {},
      });
    expect(requestAuthentication).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense, Login doesn't actually use the children prop so the LoginForm you're passing props to never gets rendered. Also you shouldn't mock out the redux hooks, just render the component in an appropriate context (see https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, the Login component does not receive any props. The component itself works exactly as intended.

I have updated my question to show the function called in LoginForm.

Comment: No, it doesn't receive any props, so why are you passing a LoginForm child when you (shallow!) render it in the test?